# The link address in htaccess redirect in php repeats the address indefinitely

Tags: php, .htaccess

After puting this code in .htaccess it infinitly repeat the url in brower for example

**https://www.example.com/mv/project/mv/project/mv/project/mv/project/mv/project...**

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [l,R=404]
```

Comment: This error shows when I write url (https://www.example.com/mv/project/) in browser but not show error when I type (https://www.example.com/mv/project/index).

Comment: Try clearing your browser caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with these lines of code `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"`, perhaps I can give some help.
This part below makes you get rid of the `.php` file extension name.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: The `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$",`  is to block any URLs that end with PHP. Perhaps OP doesn't want users to type .PHP extension in URL.

Comment: This is just repeating the code in the question (and asking a question about the code in the question - which should be a comment at best)!?